# How to make notify-send notifications permanent (to stay there even after reboot) in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: notification

I'm using below test command on Ubuntu 22.04 (Nvidia 530.41.03 from Ubuntu Repo with X11, vanilla setup no extensions etc.):

```
notify-send -u critical "Header" "Body text"
```

The notificaiton is presented as pop-up and also in the list that is presented after clicking "Date Hour" sub-menu, all good.

But without any interaction or dismissing it I perform a reboot and after reboot that notificaiton is gone from the "Date Hour" sub-menu.

Is there way how to make it permanent? So it will not disappear without manual user intervention even after reboot(s)?

Best regards

Comment: The developers did not intend notifications to be persistent (nor critical). Messages that are both important and persistent should be logged, emailed, use a dialog box, and/or use other methods to both attract attention and to be saved/regurgitated.